# Simple reading async api request in angular app not working

Tags: angular, api, observable

I just want to read data from my api, but I can't get to the structure, only observable or promise. My service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AttractionService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async getAtttractions(): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    return this.http.get<any>("https://localhost:7273/api/Attraction/Attractions");
  }
}
```

And my call in my component in ngOnInit:

```
constructor(private attractionService: AttractionService) { }

  async ngOnInit(){
    let y;
    await this.attractionService.getAtttractions()
      .then(x => {
        y = x;
      })
    console.log(y);
  }
```

Currently I getting in console.log this:

```
Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}
```

How to get my structure (api call is working fine).

Answer (score 0):

The Angular http library uses [Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables), which is a different pattern than promises/await. Your code should be:

```
this.attractionService.getAttractions()
    .subscribe(x => {
        y = x;
        console.log(y);
    });
```

EDIT:

If you absolutely need to `await`, [then convert the observable to a promise](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise):

```
await firstValueFrom(this.attractionService.getAttractions());
```

Edit 2:

Your code inside the attractionService does not need to return a promise at all. It should return the Observable, not the promise of an Observable. Angular http services does not use promises at all unless you force it to by converting the Observable to a promise.

Comment: Yes but I want to move data outside subscribe to show it in my application frontend, when I console log it inside subscribe then I got my data but it's wrong place for it, I want it outside

Comment: @Yardi I updated my answer to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I make it maybe more simpler to understand what I want:

```
async ngOnInit(){
    let thereIWantData;
    await this.attractionService.getAtttractions()
      .then(thereNot1 => {
        console.log("Data from promise")
        console.log(thereNot1);
        thereNot1.pipe(first()).subscribe(thereNot2 => {
          thereIWantData = thereNot2
          console.log("Data from observable")
          console.log(thereNot2);
        })
      })
    console.log("There i want data from observable")
    console.log(thereIWantData);
  }
```

And my logs:

```
Data from promise
Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}
There i want data from observable
undefined
Data from observable
[{…}]
```

I want to get [ {...} ] instead of undefined